# gcc debug log files on Windows?

Tags: c++, debugging, gcc

I am starting to ship Qt applications built using MinGW and have a question about debug logs.  When using code compiled with MSVC, if my app were to crash a log file or mini-dump could be created that was invaluable when diagnosing the problem.  There is even a very cool library called [crashrpt](http://code.google.com/p/crashrpt/) that can generate and then email this log file back home automatically.

Will I be blessed with the same debugging logs when an application built using gcc crashes?  If not, are there any tools out there that can produce useful logs that I can use to diagnose problems?

Comment: Are you asking about logfiles  produced when GCC crashes or when your application crashes?

Answer (score 1):

By default applications compiled with GCC do not produce a log when they crash - you will have to do that yourself somehow. On some platforms (not Windows), they may produce a core dump, which can be used for debugging, but this is nothing to do with GCC specifically.

Comment: as a side note, I've never seen one of my app built with MSVC produce a log file when crashing -- how to get this behavior?

Answer (score 0):

(old question, answer for fellow googlers)

Gcc has a [verbose termination handler](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/termination.html#support.termination.verbose) which is more limited but could still be useful.

It attempts to display the cause of unwanted termination, most likely uncaught exceptions.